# Is there a way override function with kotlin extension

Tags: android, swift, kotlin

We can override function on Swift programming like below.

```
// ---------- BaseClass.swift -------------

public class BaseClass
{
    public var method1:(Int) -> String { return doMethod1 }

    public init() {}
}

// the extension could also be in a separate file  
extension BaseClass
{    
    private func doMethod1(param:Int) -> String { return "BaseClass \(param)" }
}
```

```
// ---------- ClassA.swift ----------

public class A:BaseClass
{
   override public var method1:(Int) -> String { return doMethod1 }
}

// this extension can be in a separate file but not in the same
// file as the BaseClass extension that defines its doMethod1 implementation
extension A
{
   private func doMethod1(param:Int) -> String 
   { 
      return "A \(param) added to \(super.method1(param))" 
   }
}
```

```
// ---------- ClassB.swift ----------
public class B:A
{
   override public var method1:(Int) -> String { return doMethod1 }
}

extension B
{
   private func doMethod1(param:Int) -> String 
   { 
      return "B \(param) added to \(super.method1(param))" 
   }
}
```

But I try to call fun BaseClass.method1 in Kotlin like below;

```
class BaseClass {
    fun method1(){
        println("method1")
    }
}

fun main() {

    fun BaseClass.method1(){
        println("method12")
    }
    BaseClass().method1()
}
```

It's print method1. If I add override, shows `Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'` error. Does anyone have a solution on this issue. I want to replace some features with the extension function without changing the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own extension function using the original one.

F.E.

Extension function:

```
fun String.toInt(){
    this.toInt()
}
```

But you want to get the abs value

```
fun String.toPositiveInt(){
    this.toInt().abs()
}
```

So I'm using the original toInt with a modification to get the number without the symbol.

Comment: I didn't mean like that. I have a class like String(but not already have, I create one new) that's BaseClass. And this class has a function that is called method1. We think this method returns 2 in BaseClass and after that, we create an extension function like fun BaseClass.method1(): Int and this return 3. But it didn't override the main class function if we print this method, it returns 2. But I want to return 3 with extension function like in swift programming